# LinqPad Exception for a basic query: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, linq, linqpad

I'm connecting to an Oracle DB using LinqPad, and for the most part, it's working fine, but for certain tables I keep getting the error message:

> ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added

I understand well enough the concept of distinct keys in a dictionary; what I don't understand is how this requirement is being violated here.

As an example, I can run the following **as SQL** from LinqPad without any problems:

```
Select * from table_name where rownum < 10
```

..but if I try to run this **as a C# Expression**, then I get the error above.

```
TableNames.Take(10);
```

Just to be clear: `OtherTables.Take(10);` works fine for many other tables; the above error only occurs for a subset of them.

**Preliminary theories**

- I initially thought this might have something to do with a column in the table having a name that conflicts with the table name.

  **Example:** A table `table_name` containing a column `table_name_s` would be mapped to a Linq entity `TableNames` with a property `TableNameS`. I thought there might be some conflict between `TableNames` and `TableNameS` internally in LinqPad here, but this is at least not a consistent error, as there are other tables with the same naming schemes, which do not cause such errors.
- Another theory is that this may somehow be related to the driver I'm using in order to connect to Oracle, but this is only a hunch (I'm using the custom "IQ" driver, which supports Oracle, MySql and SQLite).

Any ideas about how to resolve and avoid this error, and be able to access the table contents using Linq?

---

**Update:** The stack trace from LinqPad, as requested.

As for the other comment: As I previously noted, I understand the root cause (a duplicate key value), but not where it is coming from. The expression `SomeTable.Take(10);`*is* essentially the whole query, only with a different table name.

```
ved System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
ved System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
ved System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
ved System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector)
ved IQToolkit.Data.Mapping.AttributeMapping.AttributeMappingEntity..ctor(Type elementType, String tableId, Type entityType, IEnumerable`1 attrs, IEnumerable`1 mappingMembers)
ved IQToolkit.Data.Mapping.AttributeMapping.CreateEntity(Type elementType, String tableId, Type entityType)
ved IQToolkit.Data.Mapping.AttributeMapping.GetEntity(Type elementType, String tableId, Type entityType)
ved IQToolkit.Data.Mapping.AttributeMapping.GetEntity(Type type, String tableId)
ved IQToolkit.Data.EntitySession.GetTable(Type elementType, String tableId)
ved IQToolkit.Data.EntitySession.GetTable[T](String tableId)
ved IQDriver.IQContextBase.GetTable[T](String name)
ved LINQPad.User.TypedDataContext.get_Phases()
ved UserQuery.RunUserAuthoredQuery() i C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad5\_jpjdzkge\query_gktujz.cs:linje 36
ved LINQPad.ExecutionModel.ClrQueryRunner.Run()
ved LINQPad.ExecutionModel.Server.RunQuery(QueryRunner runner)
```

Comment: Post the *actual* query and *actual* exception text, not just parts of them. Test data would help a lot too. `Take()` doesn't generate dictionaries, so there must be a `ToDictionary()` call or custom code that inserts results into dictionaries. The cause of the problem should be clear - duplicate key values generated by the `keySelector` parameter to `ToDictionary`

Comment: BTW it's not even clear where that `ArgumentException` comes from. It could be from a `ToDictionary` call, or not

Comment: Perhaps LinqPad is trying to create a dictionary for display purposes, but the actual data violate the entity's PK constraint, returning duplicate values? The full exception, especially the stack trace, would show which chain of calls threw that error

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've updated my question. As you can see from the stack trace, the issue appears to be related to the IQToolkit, which I suspect is used in the custom driver. So essentially, my question is, can I somehow manipulate the mapping of `my_table` so as to avoid this conflict, wherever it is coming from?

Comment: in that case it's a bug. What does the data look like? Perhaps the table has no PK that would prevent duplicates, but an `ID` column that the toolkit picked as a PK by convention? Have you tried *changing* the ORM too? Linqpad can be configured to work with EF and even EF Core.

Comment: What's the schema? [IQToolkit](https://github.com/mattwar/iqtoolkit) is open source and `ToDictionary` is called on a type's [member names](https://github.com/mattwar/iqtoolkit/blob/master/src/IQToolkit.Data/Mapping/AttributeMapping.cs#L1072). For some reason, the type ends up containing duplicate names (?!)

Comment: The stack trace shows that the code is saved in a temporary file at `C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad5\_jpjdzkge\query_gktujz.cs`. What does that contain?